# How can I scroll the whole list in UWP with Listview and Grid as parent?

Tags: listview, uwp, grid, scrollview

I've already seen this question pass by a few times here, but I still haven't found my answer.
I've tried everything, but that damn list won't scroll whole the way down. I tried putting it in a stackpanel, a scrollviewer as parent, setting height to *, or auto, or fixed, either inside the grid or inside the listview itself. But nothing seems the work. Could somebody here please help me? Thank you.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
        <ListBox x:Name="categoryListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Button 
                            Content="{Binding}"
                            Command="{Binding DataContext.GetProductsFromCategoriesCommand, ElementName=pageFoodAndDrinks}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>
    <ContentDialog 
                x:Name="ContentDialog"
                PrimaryButtonText="Order"
                CloseButtonText="Cancel">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Do you wish to order?"></TextBlock>
            <TextBox x:Name="amount"></TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </ContentDialog>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <StackPanel>
            <ListView x:Name="productsListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" SelectionChanged="ProductsListView_SelectionChangedAsync">
                <ListView.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Padding="12" Background="{ThemeResource SystemBaseLowColor}">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="900"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Product" Style="{ThemeResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Description" Style="{ThemeResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="Price" Style="{ThemeResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.HeaderTemplate>
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid x:Name="Product">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="900"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding ProductName}" TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxWidth="150"></TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding ProductDescription}" TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxWidth="800"></TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding ProductPrice}" TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxWidth="150"></TextBlock>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Hi, I truly want to help you solve this problem, but I want to confirm some things with you first. I copied your code and created a small demo, but I am a bit puzzled by what you said `scroll the whole list`. Are you meaning to *1. Scrolling the ListBox at the top*, *2. Scrolling the ListView but keeping the Header still at the top* , or *3. Let the ListBox and ListView scroll together*?

Comment: The stackpanel that contains the listbox does not need to scroll, it's the header for my view, only the listview should scroll.  Right now, the listbox inside the stackpanel does not scroll, which is good. And the listview only scrolls a little bit, I can't seem to be able to scroll further then a few elements, so 2 is what I need

Comment: You have given a `ScrollViewer` outside `ListView` which means literally there are two `ScrollViewer`. One which is outside and the other one which is inside `ListView` by default. You can disable the `ScrollViewer` inside the `ListView` by setting this property ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code you have provided i can see few issues.

1.You can't place a `ListBox` or `ListView` inside a **Row** which **height** is Defined as **`Auto`**. It makes the `ScrollViewer` within them useless.

2.Never place a `ListBox` or `ListView` within `StackPanel` which will disable **DataVirtualization**. Without `DataVirtualization` handling larger data will be a mess.

3.Do not Keep ContentDialog in Between main UI element's

Below is modified code which will scroll `ListView` and `ListBox` seperately

```
    <ContentDialog 
                x:Name="ContentDialog"
                PrimaryButtonText="Order"
                CloseButtonText="Cancel">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Do you wish to order?"></TextBlock>
            <TextBox x:Name="amount"></TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </ContentDialog>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListBox Grid.Row="0" x:Name="categoryListBox" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Button 
                            Content="{Binding}"
                            Command="{Binding DataContext.GetProductsFromCategoriesCommand, ElementName=pageFoodAndDrinks}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>

            <ListView x:Name="productsListView" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" SelectionChanged="ProductsListView_SelectionChangedAsync">
                <ListView.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Padding="12" Background="{ThemeResource SystemBaseLowColor}">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="900"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Product" Style="{ThemeResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Description" Style="{ThemeResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="Price" Style="{ThemeResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.HeaderTemplate>
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid x:Name="Product">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="900"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding ProductName}" TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxWidth="150"></TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding ProductDescription}" TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxWidth="800"></TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding ProductPrice}" TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxWidth="150"></TextBlock>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
</Grid>
```

## Edit

You can use the structure above or Simply set this property for `ListView` **ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"** in your code. this will fix the issue by stopping the default `ScrollViewer` within `ListView`

Comment: I have tried it, it doesn't work either. It scrolls a little just like before, but it still ain't possible to scroll whole the way down